# Django; How to do conditionals for custom templatetags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've been working on Django project. Seems like conditionals doesn't work for templatetags. How can I make it work?

my custom templatetag is like this.

```
register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_counts(context):
    ...
    return counts
```

and in templates

```
{% load app_name_tags %}
...
{% if not get_counts == 0 %}
{% get_counts %}
{% endif %}
```

but this conditional doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, maybe it will work:

```
{% get_counts as counts %}
{% if not counts == 0 %}
{{ counts }}
{% endif %}
```